# Problem with string compare in if condition in c++

Tags: c++, string, getline

I am trying to input a string with whitespace until the end of the file. Then I am comparing it with another string in a if condition
and the condition says, if the string matches it will print True, else False. But something is wrong with my code. According to my input all the output should be "True". But it prints true only for the last line.
Whats going wrong here?

Code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    #endif
    
    string s;

    while(getline(cin, s)){
        if(s == "my name is corey")
            cout<<"True"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"false"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Input :

```
my name is corey
my name is corey
my name is corey
my name is corey
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
True
```

Comment: Is there any chance the input includes CRLF line endings and you're testing this on an OS that uses LF line endings? The input in this question is LF, but there might be a chance.

Comment: I am using Linux and I have no knowledge about CRLF or LF line ending.

Comment: CRLF means that each line ending is comprised of the character for a carriage return (0D in ASCII) followed by the character for a line feed (0A in ASCII). This is the style Windows uses. When you get text with no context, it could use either. You can check this fairly easily on Linux by grabbing a couple lines and running `xxd <<< "<paste lines here>"` (no doubt not the simplest way, but if it works, it works). You can also print the string you get in C++ byte by byte to discover any extra invisible characters such as a trailing carriage return.

Comment: I suggest you add a bit of debugging output. You could change the line `cout<<"false"<<endl;` to `cout << "false, was: \"" << s << "\" Length: " << s.length() << endl;` and show us the new output. By printing the length of the string, we will also be able to see if it is possibly a CRLF problem.

Comment: @ArifShahriar: Note that you can edit your question to provide additional information. This may be better than posting as a comment, as comments have several limitations.